# Use of probably

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, differences

> I know that I will probably go back to my house soon anyway so I don't
>   want to fully decorate.

Does it mean...

**I know that I will probably go back to my house soon anyway so probably I don't want to fully decorate it?**

Comment: If you give us a sentence out of context we can only guess at its meaning. I take it that the person is living in temporary accommodation and doesn't want to spend too much money on it because they expect to return to their own home soon..

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the pronoun *it* in your rephrased version is strange.

Based on the sentence alone, the only thing *it* could be referring to is the house you will go back to. But to say you won't decorate the house you'll go back to because you'll go back to it soon makes little sense.

Although grammatical, this is confusing and doesn't logically follow:

> ✘ I know that I will probably go back to **my house** soon anyway so I don't want to fully decorate **it**.

If you *were* to go back somewhere, you would think the opposite would be true: that you *would* want to fully decorate it.

---

As suggested by a comment under your question, it's more reasonable to assume that you are staying somewhere else temporarily.

As such, an interpretation without the pronoun would be more sensible:

> ✔ I know that I will probably go back to **my house** soon anyway so I don't want to fully decorate **the place where I'm staying**.

It would make sense because most people don't want to put in a lot of effort on something that is only temporary.

---

Note that while this hopefully helps clarify the meaning of the sentence (as much as it can be clarified without context), it doesn't address the *title* of your question.

Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probably), *probably* means:

> : insofar as seems reasonably true, factual, or to be expected
>   : without much doubt
>   // is *probably* happy
>   // it will *probably* rain